# Trying to join a table of individuals to a table of couples, give a family ID and not time out the server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have one table with fake individual tax records like so (one row per filer):

```
T1:
+-------+---------+---------+
| Person| Spouse  | Income  |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     1 |       2 |   34000 |
|     2 |       1 |   10000 |
|     3 |    NULL |   97000 |
|     4 |       6 |   11000 |
|     5 |    NULL |   25000 |
|     6 |       4 |  100000 |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

I have a second table which has tax 'families', a single individual or married couple (one line per tax 'family').

```
T1_Family:
+-------- -+-------+---------+
| Family_id| Person| Spouse  |
+-------- -+-------+---------+
|        2 |     2 |       1 |
|        3 |     3 |    NULL |
|        5 |     5 |    NULL |
|        6 |     6 |       4 |
+------ ---+-------+---------+
```

*Family* = max(Person) within a couple

The idea of joining the two is for example, to sum the income of 2 people in one tax family (aggregate to the family level).

So, I've tried the following:

```
select *
into family_table
from
    (
        (select * from T1_family)a
    join
        (select * from T1)b
    on a.family = b.person **or a.spouse = b.person**
    )
where family_id is not null and person is not null
```

What I should get (and I do get when I select 1 random couple) is one line per individual where I can then group by family_id and sum income, pension contributions, etc. BUT SQL times out before the tables can be joined. The part in bold is what's slowing down the process but I'm not sure what else to do.

Is there an easier way to group by family?

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: 4 has 6 as spouse, but 6 has 5 as spouse... What does 4 think about that?

Comment: @jarlh whoops! save that for Jerry Springer. What I'm after is one line per individual BUT each person is flagged with their family_id so I can aggregate individual income, etc. by the family_id flag.

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to normalize your data. For starters, notice that the "spouse" column occurs in two different tables, but should presumably have the same meaning. Perhaps the family relationship should be in the individual's (T1) table - a reference to the family table.

Comment: It may seem counterintuitive at first, but getting the data normalized in a model that best relates to the real relationship usually makes getting the best query. Cheers!

Comment: @PeteKelley I see what you mean and I think the solution is easier than I expect - it may just be my overthinking causing my downfall.

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to put the data on one row:

```
select a.*, p.income as person_income, s.income as spouse_income
into family_table
from t1_family a left join
     t1 p
     on a.person = p.person lef tjoin
     t1 s
     on a.spouse = s.person;
```

Of course, you can add them together as well.

Comment: t1_family and t1 p could be linked by inner join since there's at least a person in a familly.

Comment: @davidc2p . . . That seems like a reasonable assumption.